# How to draw data file column with very small data difference using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, matlab-figure

I have a data file with 7 columns in which I need to draw the first column versus 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th column. 
The data file looks like the following:

```
1.005146    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.006025    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.008025    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.010025    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.012025    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.014025    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.015146    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.016025    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.018025    1   2   0   0   0   0
1.020025    1   2   0   0   0   0
......
```

when I try to plot the graph using the following command, I got only one point:

```
plot "queuelength.txt" using 4 with linespoints 1
```

and a warning to adjust both x and y range. So to fix it I use the actual x and y range

```
plot [0:40][0:50] "queuelength.txt" using 4 with linespoints 1
```

But I got nothing!! so I've tried to change the first column data for 10 rows from 1 to 10 and it works!! so does that mean gnuplot can't deal with a data that has very small difference equals to 0.002 between each row?
Is there anyway to deal with it or to draw it using gnuplot?

Comment: Well, you don't use the first column. With `plot "..." using 4` you use the row number as x-value and the fourth column with only zeros as y-value.

Comment: @Christoph so how should I fix it. I already tried using 1:4 and I got nothing as well. The y-value started with zero then it has other values

Comment: Simply using `reset; plot "queuelength.txt" using 1:4` should work fine. If not, please upload your data file somewhere

Comment: @Christoph I already tried it and didn't work. Kindly find the result file on this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz9dplMzAYA6blFEQWpqTmJWdVk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your data file contains only carriage returns (ASCII 13, `\r`) as line endings. Gnuplot cannot handle those properly. You must have line feeds (ASCII 10, `\n`), or both `\r\n` as line endings.

What works for me is

```
plot '< sed ''s/\r/\n/g'' qlength_map1.txt' using 1:4
```

Comment: I have tried the command you suggest but it didn't work and I've got the following message: gnuplot> plot '< sed''s/\r/\n/g'' qlength_map1.txt' using 1:4
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: seds/\r/\n/g
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: seds//r//n/g
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
/bin/sh: seds/\r/\n/g: No such file or directorywarning: Skipping data file with no valid points
         x range is invalid

Comment: Did you copy&paste the command? According to your error message you are missing an space after 'sed'