# Gnuplot only Plotting one Dot instead of all data

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot time vs entropy of a data. When I run the script, it just produces a graph with one dot on y axis and no plot. Here is my script:

```
set terminal png
set output 'output.png'
set xdata time
set timefmt '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'
set format x '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'
set xrange ['"2008-01-01 00:00"':'"2008-03-20 00:00"']
set yrange [0.5:2.4]
set style data lines
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Entropy"
plot "foobar-entropy.txt" using 1:2 w lp ls 4 lw 3
```

And here is the data:

```
"2008-01-01 02:13:38"   1.0
"2008-01-10 02:12:13"   1.5
"2008-01-20 02:11:55"   1.459
"2008-01-30 02:10:28"   1.811
"2008-02-10 02:09:44"   1.722
"2008-02-20 02:08:00"   1.65
"2008-02-28 02:07:00"   2.149
"2008-03-10 02:06:00"   2.18
"2008-03-20 02:04:00"   2.33
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd be inclined to try removing the quote marks from around the date field in the data file and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Having said that, I just put your data and script gnuplot exactly as you've got it and it draws a reasonable line graph with a bunch of points. What version of gnuplot are you using? (I'm running 5.2 patchlevel 2, last modified 2017-11-15)

Comment: I removed all the quotes from the data and also removed the single quotes from `timefmt` and `format` and `xrange` but still the same result.

Comment: It is  Version 5.0 patchlevel 3    last modified 2016-02-21

Comment: Work out-of-the-box for me using Gnuplot Version 5.0 patchlevel 7 on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working for me. I have a macOS with GNUPlot Version 5.2 patchlevel 0 and an Ubuntu with GNUPlot Version 5.0 patchlevel 3. It gives the same result on both. Here is the output [image](https://imgur.com/TdYDnca).

Comment: In the image you `plot "foobar-nodes-entrogy.txt"` which is a different file. Maybe you are simply plotting the wrong file on your system, which would also explain why it works for all other that follow the instructions in your question.

Comment: It is the same file, I just kept the name short for posting here. I don't know what is going on with gnuplot on my computers. It plot other plots. just for this script, it produces blank plot.

Comment: Hmm, last guess: you have wrong line breaks in the data file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374977/2604213

Comment: That was helpful @Christoph . I have added an answer for it explaining the issue. Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found the mystery after @Christoph told about the line breaks. The issue was that the file had different line endings which gnuplot do not support.
When I opened the file with **vi** editor it appeared as follows:

```
"2008-01-01 02:13:38"   1.0^M
"2008-01-10 02:12:13"   1.5^M
"2008-01-20 02:13:55"   1.459^M
"2008-01-30 02:12:28"   1.811^M
"2008-02-10 02:12:44"   1.722^M
"2008-02-20 02:13:00"   1.65^M
"2008-02-28 02:13:00"   2.149^M
"2008-03-10 02:13:00"   2.18^M
"2008-03-20 02:13:00"   2.33^M
```

After running the command [**dos2unix**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/files/) on the file, it changed the old-style carriage-return characters to linefeeds and it works fine now.